# Slider product category home page

Tags: blocks, home, slider

I must to make a slider products.

My theme is venedor.

I used this code

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="10" products_count="4" template="catalog/product/list/featured_slider.phtml"}}
```

but i see 3 products. for see 4 product i need to use arrow.

My code is erroneous

Comment: you want to product slider right

Comment: I bought this theme

http://newsmartwave.net/magento/venedor/pink/

i want to replicate "latest" product. I want to slide my category_id 10.
in the exemple there is 4 products. with my code 3 products. why?

Comment: which theme you are using

Comment: venedor pink color

Comment: Show me that code or check any backend option is there

Comment: in top page i have insert the block code

Comment: what you want exactly

Answer (score 1):

you have to set the IsWide to either 0 or 1. If set to 1 it will be 4 products wide. From memory it think its..

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" iswide="1" category_id="10" products_count="4" template="catalog/product/list/featured_slider.phtml"}}
```

Either that or edit the template and set on line 131..

```
<?php $isWideSlider = 1; ?>
```